# Nested While Loop where "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, while-loop, nested

For the program that I am trying to write I need to use both a Switch case and a While loop. I have no problem with the Switch example, however I'm not sure how to get a similar solution with a While loop.

I am trying to evaluate a user entered value with a nested while loop.
In it I want to allow the user to "select" any number between and including 3 through 10. (Assume that using System etc is all correct)

```
static void Main()
{
     int userInput;  //user enters int with ReadLine
     int defaultInt = 3; //user keys anything other than 3 through 10

     Console.WriteLine("Enter an Integer");
     userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     InputCheck();
     Console.WriteLine("The number you have chosen is {0}", userInput

}

public int InputCheck()
{
    while (userInput >= 3) 
    {
         while (userInput <= 10)
         {
             return userInput;
         }
         while (userInput > 10)
         {
             return defaulInt = userInput;
         }
     while (userInput < 3)
     {
        return defaultInt = userInput;
     }
}
```

Is something like this even possible to do with a while loop?
I know it would be easier to do this as a Switch but I have already done that in this program and need to implement a While loop.

Comment: There's no reason to use `while`. Use `if` (since you default to 3 without asking for re-entry). Your actual error is because you don't return anything if `userInput < 3`

Comment: I sincerely doubt that this code is what your teacher meant by "use a while loop". Are you sure you weren;t supposed to ask for input and evaluate it repeatedly, until the user enters some value like "QUIT"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` statement is actually what you are looking for, not `while`.
Talking about `if` usage, code convenience and readability, I would also rearrange it this way:

```
public int InputCheck()
{
    if (userInput > 10) 
        return defaultInt = userInput;

    if (userInput >= 3)
        return userInput;

    return defaultInt = userInput;
}
```

Look, it now looks better, but does the same thing.
Two of your `if` conditions were actually redundant since they are guaranteed to be `true` according to previous conditions.

However, your code is still non-working...

1. What is that: `defaultInt = userInput`? Do you really want to override the value of defaultInt. Name default suggests that it shouldn't be.
2. Also, you try to access local variables in another method, which is impossible.
3. You are missing a couple parentheses and curly braces.

Please, be sure to fully read and understand this material before asking next questions:

- [MSDN if-else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)
- [MSDN while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx)
- [Dotnetperls if](https://www.dotnetperls.com/if)
- [Dotnetperls while](https://www.dotnetperls.com/while)

Comment: Yes, I think this looks much better! Using your code I was able to get it to work by adding a top limit with "if (userHeightInput <= 10)"

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of a `while` loop in your situation is to keep the program asking for `userInput` until it is happy with the input value. However you have a `while` loop but your function doesn't give an opportunity to fix the incorrect value of `userInput`.

I've rearranged the logic a little so that the user has a chance to fix input errors inside the `while` loop.

```
    static void Main()
    {
         // `userInput` and `defaultInt` are only visible inside this function
         // so you won't have access to them in InputCheck() unless you pass them in as parameters ...

         int userInput = -1;  //user enters int with ReadLine
         int defaultInt = 3; //user keys anything other than 3 through 10
         bool ok = false;       // flag to keep you in the while loop until the userInput is acceptable

         while (!ok)    // while we are *not* ok - the while-condition is checked at the top of the while-loop
         {
             // Give user a chance to fix `userInput` inside the while loop
             Console.WriteLine("Enter an Integer from 3 to 10");    // let the user know what the valid inputs are
             userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());             // need to fix!! if user enters non-integer, eg "quit", this will throw an exception

             ok = InputCheck(userInput);
             // You have a choice here:
             // You can keep looping until user specifies a number from 3 to 10

             // Or you can simply override a bad choice with your default.
             // If you don't want the default logic, get rid of the following block
             if ( !ok )
             {
                 // Let the user know what you're doing
                 Console.WriteLine("Overriding your invalid choice {0} to {1}", userInput, defaultInt);
                 userInput = defaultInt;    // override user's choice
                 ok = true;                 // force the while loop to exit
             }

         }
         Console.WriteLine("The number you have chosen is {0}", userInput);
    }

    // Move the while loop out of `InputCheck` function.
    // InputCheck now has only one job - to check that userInput is acceptable

    public bool InputCheck(int userInput)    // you have to pass `userInput` in as parameter - it is only visible in Main()
    {
        if (3 <= userInput && userInput <= 10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int InputCheck()
{
    if (userInput >= 3) 
    {
         if (userInput <= 10)
         {
             return userInput;
         }
         if (userInput > 10)
         {
             return defaulInt = userInput;
         }
      }
     if (userInput < 3)
     {
        return defaultInt = userInput;
     }
}
```

Comment: My IDE would suggest that two `if`s are redundant :)

Comment: This doesn't compile - it has the exact same error as in the title.